# CodeIgniter URI Not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use this code :

```
$url =  $this->uri->segment_array()// OR $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3);
print_r($url);
```

but it always return empty array ?
the requested URL like  :
`http://localhost/my_proj/index.php/thumb/index/id/87`

Comment: does `echo $this->uri->segment(3);` echo the appropriate result?

Comment: @Ross : no result return from it , i digging inside CI trying to know where the problem two days on it :| .

Comment: post your thumb/index controller, and put `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` in your `_construct` function. It will return all sorts of information like the current URI. if this appears correctly, it would seem the URI class is having problems.

Comment: `http://localhost/my_proj/index.php/thumb/index/id/1` , when i run the profiler its say s:` URI STRING: No URI data exists .`

Comment: The problem was that i put URI class inside the autoload conf array :S , Thanks rose anyway .

Comment: i too facing the same problem. 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912283/codeigniter-uri-segment-not-working-properly-getting-output-as-0/][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912283/codeigniter-uri-segment-not-working-properly-getting-output-as-0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url =  $this->uri->segment_array();
print_r($url);
```

this code works  tested with codeigniter 1.7.2,
did u check your router configuration file ?

Comment: I checked it , the same :( , i re-download  from CI site , the same also .

Comment: which server u are using, is it xampp, wampp ??
and where did u installed this codeigniter framework ?

Comment: i dont use packages like : xampp, wampp , I use Apache with different mods & PHP 5.3 on ubuntu

Comment: that mean uri_protocol is not working for u, in your configuration folder config.php->$config['uri_protocol'] play around with different settings, there is nice comment there as well explaining the options.