# codeigniter uri segment not working properly getting output as 0

Tags: codeigniter, uri

`localhost/backend/administrator/authentication/8218/0`

In codeigniter, I want to fetch these values 8218 and 0.

My code is:

```
class Administrator extends Controller {

function Administrator()
    {
            parent::Controller();
            $this->load->library('uri');
    }

function authentication()
    {        
        echo $seg1= $this->uri->segment(3);
        echo $seg2 = $this->uri->segment(4);
        echo $this->uri->total_segments(); 
    }

}
```

I am not getting any output, but I got out put as '0' when I used  `$this->uri->total_segments();`

```
my config.php 

'AUTO'          Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|

$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";

i am using .htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /backend/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]    

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Can any one find out my mistake and suggest me the correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to load the core library. It has been loaded automatically for you. Remove the following line from the constructor, and everything should be working.

```
$this->load->library('uri');
```

Comment: yeah thanks , it solved me , i removed this line and it works fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Load this `$this->load->helper('url');`
Codigniter use controller/Method/param/param . so you access these values like this.

```
 function authentication($first_calue = '0', $second_value='0')
        {        
            echo $seg1= $this->uri->segment(3);
            echo $seg2 = $this->uri->segment(4);
            echo $this->uri->total_segments(); 
            echo $first_calue;
            echo $second_value;

        }
```

Comment: even though i am getting values as 0 only. i want 8218 and 0 , how could i get these values using uri segment in codeigniter

Comment: i have already loaded url helper , uri libraray in the config.php

Comment: you can try this by loading that in controller.......:( ...I have used it sevral times and its works 100 out of 100 times for me..

Comment: i am not getting any out put  i am getting just a blank white page,  is there any problem because of .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

IF you always have this url structure for this controller method I would recommend you use method arguments. The way controller methods usually  deal with url segments is by declaring them as method arguments:

```
public function method_name($agr_1 = 0, $arg_2 = 0)
```

Here $arg_1 will hold  8218, and $arg_2 - 0

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the library in the codeignitor 
Just start the code
             
            `$this->uri->segment(3);`