# Codeigniter not recognising controllers and methods after server move

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Have moved a codeigniter application to a new server.

Had to update virtual hosts etc. to allow .htaccess file to work - initially got a page not found error.

Now, the application is loading the default welcome screen, regardless of what URL is accessed i.e.

domain.com/admin/edit

Have used the following to see what class / method is being loaded:

```
<? echo $this->router->fetch_class();?>
<br /><br/>
<? echo $this->router->fetch_method();?>
```

and this shows:

```
welcome 

index
```

(where I would expect 'admin' and 'edit')

Looking at a print_r of $_SERVER in the welcome file, I can see the following:

```
[QUERY_STRING] => /admin/edit/
```

Which to me suggests .htaccess is doing its job?

Any ideas what I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that mod_rewrite is not enabled, or you missed rewrite rulles in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

From here: [CodeIgniter URI Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221319/codeigniter-uri-not-working)

I discovered that using this:

```
$url =  $this->uri->segment_array();
print_r($url);
```

gave an empty array.

From the comments, this sorted it out:

that mean uri_protocol is not working for u, in your configuration folder config.php->$config['uri_protocol'] play around with different settings, there is nice comment there as well explaining the options

Comment: Edit your post instead of posting updated finds as answer